# Using CartoDB to detect user location and put dot on map?

Tags: carto, geolocation, carto-js

I have a CartoDB question.

We have a project we are piloting in Rio das Pedras, Brazil, a favela near Rio.

We have sampling points, working on adding Fulcrum photo uploads and some pretty bad road linework from a university there, but the labels are helpful for our field team. 
http://beh-gis.github.io/maps/rdp_loc.html

For this map, I’m trying to add a GPS dot, that shows where the user is. I grabbed some code from a CartoDB example (http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/query_by_distance.html) and it asks the user to use location but seems to Error out or something.

Here’s the html code:
https://github.com/beh-gis/beh-gis.github.com/blob/master/maps/rdp_loc.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `map` variable you're referring to doesn't exist in the scope where you're attempting to use it. There are a few ways to handle this, but with a relatively small page like this I would just make sure you define the variable outside of any function ("globally"). Eg:

```
<script> // credit: http://html5doctor.com/finding-your-position-with-geolocation/
var map;  // This is the bit I added.
function detectUserLocation(){
    ...
```

Then when you set the variable later, don't use `var` again (that would redefine it). So instead of

```
var map = vis.getNativeMap();
```

use

```
map = vis.getNativeMap();
```

Finally, if you plan on using JavaScript more I'd recommend getting acquainted with the Developer Tools for your browser of choice. They should help you get a better idea of why your pages don't work the way you expect them to. And I'd recommend using a service like [jsbin](http://jsbin.com) to post code so others can quickly see it in use and try it.